# Windows 8 unresponsive, how to find faulting process, service or driver?

Tags: windows

My computer is running Windows 8 Enterprise, X64. It hides a quite descent hardware: Core I7, 16GB of Ram and a 500GB 7200rpm sata drive.

However, I often have some lags. Not the whole computer is lagging, but some apps. When this occurs, opening Windows Explorer for example, take more than two minutes (with no visible other activity).

[image]

The performance monitor show a near-idle CPU usage, memory is not empty, and the disk is working normally -I think a disk queue < to 1 is correct). Moreover, I have development computer that perform very well with 8Gb of ram (using Hyper-V), even while some apps are lagging

But some apps are still lagging. Most of time, metro apps, but not only.

After a reboot (when I can, sometimes event triggering the reboot is not possible)

**It seems that *something* is in a weird state** and lagging apps are waiting for that.

I have installed all possible hotfixes, drivers update, etc. but still having issues.

**I know you wont be able to identify the problem for me**, but I hope **you'll indicate me what kind of diagnostics I can run to see what's going wrong**.

Because only some apps are experiencing issues, I guess this is because of one root dependency (a service, a driver, etc.).

I dive into the event logs, which no useful information.

I also have process explorer started, but I'm not sure what to look at.

**[Edit] Some weeks later, I still have my stability issues**

But I was able to narrow my search. Actually, I can see this in the resource monitor:

[image: Resource monitor]

Every time I'm in a hanged situation, I can see that the `Remote procedure call service`' process is at the root of the wait chain.

And unfortunately, this service cannot simply be restarted as it's a mandatory service, root of many windows components.

How can I diagnose this service?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when my laptop was on battery.

By default (at least on my configuration) Windows 8 had a "System cooling policy" as "passive" on battery mode. So each time I opened a web page with lots of js and flash I had a huge lags! The reason for that was - CPU was working really hard => temperature increased => since "cooling policy" was "passive" the cooler didn't run => CPU decreased frequency => huge lags.

Check your settings at:
Control panel => power options => click on "Change plan settings" in the currently selected plan => click "change advanced power settings" => navigate to "Processor power management" node and expand it.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm running plugged, with Performance mode.

Comment: Moreover, when the computer lags, only some applications are lagging... not all